# Logstash old json schema output

Tags: logstash

The logstash json schema was changed in logstash 1.2.0. In which the "@" prefix and the "@fields" group was removed. It broke some of my programs since the code was built with the old schema. Is there any way to get logstash output with the old json schema?

I am using file input and elasticsearch output. I tried adding "codec => oldlogstashjson" in the output configuration, but it changed nothing.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same question on logstash GitHub.

There is an answer :

```
Elasticsearch is deprecating rivers soon. You should not be using this output. It is not being carried over to Logstash 1.5.

In Logstash 1.4.2, the elasticsearch_river plugin does not support using the output codec, which is why it does not work for you.
```

Comment: But I am not using the elasticsearch_river plugin. Instead, I am using elasticsearch.